# jQueryUI sortable re-binding on update

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a `<ul>` tag that is "hardcoded" in my markup:

So, something like:

```
<ul id='myList'></ul>
```

and then I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Some code
   $("#myList").sortable();
//Some more code
});
```

Now, my issue lies when I update the `<ul>` dynamically with a button click. The list in question gets generated by the user at runtime. So, when the page loads with some data in it (it's all stored in the database) the `<li>` objects are all listed properly and created as expected as `.sortable()`. Once I add a new entry, the entire list reverts to a list with bullet points showing, and no longer `.sortable();`. When the user enters data, the data is stored to the data and returned to the client via JSON (ie. no postback).

So, my question is, is there a way to re-bind the `.sortable();` on the fly so that the list never falls back to a standard `<li>` element and will always be `.sortable();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/VxYmw/1/) based on your code.  Is there something I'm missing - I'm not seeing the behavior that you describe.  I'm using jQuery 1.6.0 (since jsFiddle doesn't have an option for 1.6.1).  But I'm using jQueryUI 1.8.13 (black tie theme, which doesn't really mean much :)  ).

I didn't need to do a refresh on `sortable` - my list updates without reverting to a basic `<UL>`.

Let me know what I'm missing and I can further refine the fiddle.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**:
I made some changes to my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/VxYmw/2/) based on your comment.  It's not 100% the same, as jsFiddle only allows POSTs for JSON echo requests, but I think it's close.  I still didn't have to do a sortable refresh; I just emptied the contents of the outer `<UL>` and then rebuild the `<LI>` elements.

Comment: Interesting. Hmm...I do a complete refresh of the list when a new item is loaded, since it's database driven. So, basically, I have `$("#buttonToAdd").click(function() {   $.getJSON('@Url.Action("/Home/AddToDatabaseAndGetNewList", {o: object}, function(data){  if(data.success) //It worked, refresh the list $("#myList").html(data.newList) });`. The method that it calls basically stores the new object in the database and generates a new set of `<li>` elements and returns it to the calling request.

Comment: @SlackerCoder - updated my answer based upon your comment.  Hopefully this is getting close.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. That got me close enough to do what I needed it to do. It's basically what you had in there, I just had to convert a bit of it!

Comment: @SlackerCoder: Glad I could help!  Great name, btw!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `.sortable('refresh')`? http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#method-refresh

Comment: I have tried it....I still doesn't refresh the listing. I'm using jquery 1.6.1 and jqueryUI 1.8.13 (most recent versions of both). I call the refresh when the new list gets returned to the client and added to the `<ul>` tag, but it doesn't do anything.